# Replacing missing date in data frame, shall i use zero, minimum date, or average?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, artificial-intelligence, data-cleaning

shall i replace NaN with zero, average, or minimum year "1900" in below case,

i am trying to clean below example dataframe the second item has no garage with 0 value in both GarageArea and GarageCars columns

**Edit:** to be clearer i am not looking for **how to?** I am looking for best value of the missing date i.e "`min, avarage, or zero`"

**without dropping row because it is a test dataset not training**

i am trying to clean this test dataframe for scikit learn randomForest using pandas, since this is a date i think using zero will not be approperiate, also i am not sure about average or minimum values!!

```
#   Year    GarageArea  GarageCars
1   1900    10           1
2   NaN     0            0
3   2001    50           2
4   1950    70           2
5   2019    100          4
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the problem you are trying to solve, but the general approach used is either `bfill()` or `ffill()`:

```
df.ffill()
     Year  GarageArea  GarageCars
1  1900.0          10           1
2  1900.0           0           0
3  2001.0          50           2
4  1950.0          70           2
5  2019.0         100           4

df.bfill()
     Year  GarageArea  GarageCars
1  1900.0          10           1
2  2001.0           0           0
3  2001.0          50           2
4  1950.0          70           2
5  2019.0         100           4
```

Comment: @jezrael true, but just wanted to add example :)

Comment: sorry but I am looking for best value of the missing date i.e "min, avarage, or zero" not how to

Answer (score 0):

if supposed GarageArea or GarageCars is NaN the we can fill them  with average value but when other field (GarageArea or GarageCars) is zero and Year is NaN then droping such row  will be best solution.

Comment: dropping not an option since it is a test sample not training